# ¿Como implementar Reporting Services en mi proyecto de ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, ssrs, reportviewerreporte

Tengo problemas para implementar Reporting Services en mi proyecto de ASP.Net ya el servidor de reportes esta configurado pero cuando estoy en la pagina e ingreso a la ventana que deberia de mostrarme el informe me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo es este

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string ssrsUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSReportsUrl"].ToString();
        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

        try
        {
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            viewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
            viewer.AsyncRendering = true;
            viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ssrsUrl);
            viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "report/CertificadoQuiron1";

            viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials("myUser", "mypassword", "www.MyDominio.com");
            viewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
            ViewBag.ReportViewer = viewer;

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```